# remove() not removing element from all parent elements of same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a load of Wordpress posts, and when the browser is below a certain size, I need to move one of the elements within each post into another element (this is a design requirement).

I am using the below to loop through each post, and move the element `post-comments` into the `post-meta` div.

```
jQuery('.post-entry').each(function(){ // Loop through each post...
  if( jQuery(this).find('.post-meta .post-comments').length == 0 ) {
    jQuery(this).find('.post-extra span.post-comments').appendTo('.post-meta'); // Move categories into the ".post-meta" div
    jQuery(this).find('.post-extra span.post-comments').remove();
  }
});
```

JSFiddle to follow, but the current behavior is that the first `post-entry` works as fine, and the `post-comments` element is moved into `post-meta` and removed from its original place, however on the other `post-entry` divs, the `post-comments` element is not being removed from its original position - can anyone see why?

Basically, I need to move `post-comments` from its original location into an element called `post-meta` on multiple posts on the page I am working on.

Comment: while you're appending post-meta you are removing it's parent. what actually you want to do here?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking...

Comment: I'm not sure I get your goal but maybe you're missing a detail : when you append an element somewhere, it's removed from its initial location.

Comment: @dystroy - Actually, when you append an element while targeting a class/element that exists more than once, append will instead CLONE the element and not remove it from its original location

Comment: @wickywills append won't clone but shift element from here to there...

Comment: @C-link wickywill seems to be right http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: @C-link - http://welcome.totheinter.net/2009/03/19/the-undocumented-life-of-jquerys-append/

Comment: @wickywills at your provided link uses get which is stored in variable so it's cloning but can't see in your code that would clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('.post-entry').each(function() {
    var $post = jQuery(this),
        $meta = $post.find('.post-meta');

    if ($meta.find('.post-comments').length == 0) {
        $post.find('.post-extra .post-comments').appendTo($meta);
    }
});
```

The difference here is that I've made sure you're always finding and appending within `$(this)`. Your length check was checking all `.post-entry`s and your appendTo was appending to **all** `.post-meta`s so the second time it iterated through the loop, the length check would not be `0`.

If you do it this way, you don't need the `.remove` at all as the `appendTo` **moves** it.

Comment: This works fine for the first post on the page, but on the other posts, the `post-comments` element isn't moved at all

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle so I can check your markup? I've made a jsbin to show the above **does** work: http://jsbin.com/pijoqoja/1/edit

Comment: Actually, this DOES work - my old JS was just cached. Thanks for a much better solution to what I was doing :)

Answer (score 1):

After moving the very first post, the following check will always fail, because it checks the first element (which you already moved):

```
if( jQuery('.post-entry').find('.post-meta .post-comments').length == 0 )
```

instead write:

```
if( $(this).find('.post-meta .post-comments').length == 0 )
```

because inside a `$().each()` loop, `this` is referencing the current element of your resulting node list:

wrong:

```
jQuery('.post-entry').each(function(){ // Loop through each post...
  if( jQuery('.post-entry') // <- does not reference the current element
```

correct:

```
jQuery('.post-entry').each(function(){ // Loop through each post...
  if( $(this) <- always references your current element of the each loop
```

Comment: Getting the same result as before - the element `post-comments` is being moved fine on the first post, but on the other posts, it is instead being cloned - very odd!

Comment: Because you do the same error with `.appendTo('.post-meta')`. You need to be consinstent with your selectors.

Comment: Unsure if it would work, but I changed appendTo to this `appendTo(jQuery(this).find('.post-meta'))` - still no luck. Only works on the first post, and not the others on the page

Comment: Sorry, this solution works - I just missed a bracket! I've marked another answer as accepted, as it was a better solution to what I was doing, but given you a +1 for your time and explanation - thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
jQuery(this).find('.post-extra span.post-comments').parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the removed element is a 'child', you can try this:

```
$('#parentElement').children().remove(); //For all childs

$('#parentElement').children('div').remove(); //For all childs that are divs


$('#parentElement').children('div.classOfDiv').remove(); //For all childs that are Divs with X class
```

If the `children()` doesn't work. Try play with `next()` and `closest()`. It helped me sometimes.

Something that helps also, to supply `find()` (that gave me problems in the past), could be this:

HTML EXAMPLE:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="class1"></li>
    <button onclick="trigger()">access the li element</button>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to access `li` you can also try something strange, but works:

```
$('this').closest('div').$('.class1').remove();  //When clicking the button, for example
```

This helped me sometimes, because `closest()` finds elements above your current location, and not beneath.

I don't have clear what you are asking, but maybe this could help you a bit.

I hope it helped you. Have good luck and let us know how it goes! ;)